# How to have zero gap when splitting cells in MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

The following code

```
public class JSplitGap extends JPanel {

   {
      setLayout(new MigLayout());
   }

   {
      JButton ans = new JButton("Button 1");
      add(ans, "split 2");
   }

   {
      JButton ans = new JButton("Button 2");
      add(ans, "");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setContentPane(new JSplitGap());
      //frame.setSize(1024, 768);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

gives the following

[image]

i.e. with some gaps between buttons.

Although it is said

> split [count] Splits the cell in a number of sub-cells. Practically
>   this means that the next count number components will be put in the
>   same cell, next to eachother without gaps. Only the first component in
>   a cell can set the split, any subsequent split keywords in the cell
>   will be ignored. count defaults to infinite if not specified which
>   means that split alone will put all coming components in the same
>   cell. "split", "wrap" or "newline" will break out of the split celll.
>   The latter two will move to a new row/column as usual. Note! "skip"
>   will will skip out if the splitting and continue in the next cell.
>   Example: "split" or "split 4".

in the [documentation](http://www.miglayout.com/whitepaper.html).

What is wrong here and how to fix?

Comment: I haven't tried that but try these respectively - > new MigLayout("insets 0 0 0 0"); or new MigLayout("fill");

Comment: Tried. `fill` has no effect, while `insets` removes outer padding, but not between buttons.

Comment: Have you tried my answer's code line ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 0", "grow"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a gap between the buttons with the the `gapx` component
constraint:

```
package com.zetcode;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class MigLayoutSplitGapEx extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutSplitGapEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        JButton ans = new JButton("Button 1");
        add(ans, "split 2");

        JButton ans2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        add(ans2, "gapx 0");

        pack();
        setTitle("MigLayout split gap");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MigLayoutSplitGapEx ex = new MigLayoutSplitGapEx();
            ex.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the screenshot:

[image]